# how to append Options in Select Box Dynamically

Tags: html, select

i want to add two options in DropBox

```
$("#payment_method_1").append(new Option("Credit", "7"));
$("#payment_method_1").append(new Option("Debit", "6"));
```

when i implement that codes it's append perfectly but the problem is it's appending so many times instead of one time

```
    <select name="payment_method_1" id="payment_method_1" class="paysome" style="opacity: 0;">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Cash</option>
    <option value="2">Credit Card</option>
    <option value="3">Western Union</option>
    <option value="4">Cheque</option>
    <option value="8">Bank</option>
    <option value="7">Credit</option>
    <option value="6">Debit</option>
    <option value="7">Credit</option>
    <option value="6">Debit</option>
    <option value="7">Credit</option>
    <option value="6">Debit</option>
    <option value="7">Credit</option>
    <option value="6">Debit</option>
    </select>
```

Here is my Loop

```
    $('.paysome').each(function(index, element) {   
    $("#payment_method_"+index).append(new Option("Credit", "7"));
    $("#payment_method_"+index).append(new Option("Debit", "6"));
    });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: such as an $.each() statement?

Comment: yes it is a loop and i already tried $.each

Comment: $('.paysome').each(function(index, element) {
        $("#payment_method_"+index).append(new Option("Credit", "7"));
            $("#payment_method_"++index).append(new Option("Debit", "6"));
                });

Comment: @NoorKhan plz check updated ans..did you get your ans or any thing else your are pointing to?

Comment: you can use `$(this)` inside a loop instead of building a new id selector with the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an option and append to your `select`

```
$('.paysome').each(function(index, element) {        
    var index = index + 1;
    var select = document.getElementById("payment_method_"+index);
    select.appendChild(new Option("Credit", "7"));
    select.appendChild(new Option("Debit", "6"));      
}
```

Or,

```
$('.paysome').each(function(index, element) {        
    var index = index + 1;
    $("#payment_method_"+index).append(new Option("Credit", "7"));
    $("#payment_method_"+index).append(new Option("Debit", "6"));              
}
```

I see issue is with index.`$.each` index starts with zero and your id index starts with 1 so you may need to update your id or update your code .

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSwhr/9/)

Comment: thanks @captain, i was searching that mistake from 4 hours :)